# Como crear un TXT desde batch sin lineas ni espacios dentro 100% Virgen

Tags: batch

He intentado hacer esto:
echo.>archivo.txt

el problema que cuando lo abro con notepad++ me dice que pesa 1 Bite osea hay un espacio y una linea adicional a la primera dentro del archivo.txt, lo que  necesito es que este a 0 Bites y 100% Virgen no puede ser de mas de 0 Bites o tener ningun caracter sea espacio lineas ,ETC. agradezco ayuda de antemano Gracias.

Comment: Si tu pregunta apunta a SO linux, la etiqueta 'batch' es incorrecta (porque corresponde a SO MS-DOS y Windows)!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

prueba con el siguiente comando touch, sus parametros son los siguientes:

> -a y -m

Estas dos opciones actualizan el tiempo de acceso y modificación respectivamente.

su uso:

```
touch -a "archivoNuevo"
```

> -c

Touch no hará nada si el archivo especificado no existe

su uso:

```
touch -c "archivoNuevo"
```

hay varios parametros mas

ahora para resolver tu problema seria asi:

```
touch "nueva carpeta"
```

Answer (score 2):

Buenos días,
¿Te refieres a crear un archivo desde la consola de comandos Windows? 
Entonces el comando es:

```
C:\Users\%USER%\Desktop>fsutil file createnew file.txt 0
El archivo C:\Users\%USER%\Desktop\file.txt está creado

C:\Users\%USER%\Desktop>dir
 El volumen de la unidad C no tiene etiqueta.

 Directorio de C:\Users\%USER%\Desktop

26/12/2016  18:12              .
26/12/2016  18:12              ..
26/12/2016  18:12                 0 file.txt
               1 archivos              0 bytes
               2 dirs  152.207.171.584 bytes libres
```